# class "ViewController' has no initializers

Tags: swift

Im trying to build a simply sound app. I want a button press to play a clip pretty much like a soundboard. problem is when I go to build it says class "ViewController' has no initializers

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func playSound(sender:UIButton){

        // Set the sound file name & extention
        let audioFilePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "emp_learntoknow", ofType: "mp3")

        if audioFilePath != nil {

            let audioFileUrl = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: audioFilePath!)
            do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFileUrl)
            audioPlayer.play()


        } catch {
            print("audio file is not found")

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: you have to add just :
` var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer? =nil`

Answer (score 12):

Because it has no initializers. You have a property:

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer
```

...but you are not initializing it. You have, of course, given it a *type*, but a type is not a *value*. All properties must have initial values.

Comment: ! <- required after AVAudioPlayer  var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

Answer (score 5):

Like Matt has mentioned, it's happening because the property is not initialized.

In Swift, you have to use optionals for variables that could be `nil` at any point. You'll have to either initialize `audioPlayer` from the beginning or use an optional type, including the implicitly unwrapped optional if you know it will be set later on and stay that way.